# How to see all references to variable in Js Chrome Developer Tool

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, google-chrome-devtools

I am debugging [CKEditor](https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev) and the Chrome developer tool doesn't show me which function is updated the value when stepping through....or i don't know how to see all the references pointing to the particular variable. How to see all the reference to a particular variable, so I can detect the execution updating value.

For details, the update happens in the following code in the dom/element.js

```
setHtml: ( CKEDITOR.env.ie && CKEDITOR.env.version < 9 ) ?
                
                function( html ) {
                    //this function is not called...
                }
            :
                function( html ) {
                 //here someone is updating this.$.innerHTML something other than 'html' value
                    return ( this.$.innerHTML = html );
                },
```

Particularly, i am interested who is updating "this.$.innerHtML value behind the scenes. Why is the return value in parentheses?

Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

This is plain old JavaScript. There's nothing happening behind the scenes. This line:

```
return ( this.$.innerHTML = html );
```

does 2 things:

1. Sets `this.$.innerHTML` to `html`.
2. Returns value of the expression in parentheses which is basically the value of `html`.

Comment: Thank You Reinmar. I am not sure but the Chrome debug tool does not show that html is set to this.$.innerHTML. Perhaps it is, but with the Chrome Debug tool its impossible to track who is doing the escaping for code tags such as "<?php" to <!--?php before or after setting it to this.$.innerHTML on the same line. Where is the escaping executed?  what triggers it (what event)? how is it referenced? if you can help, I will much appriciate

Comment: You're looking in a completely wrong place. As I wrote - there's no magic behind that code. It just sets the `innerHTML`. What you're referring to is done in a different place of code, here: https://github.com/ckeditor/ckeditor-dev/blob/master/core/htmldataprocessor.js#L847-L909

Comment: Thank you Reinmar. I hope to get back on this over the weekend. You reference is very helpful. Thank You